# PHP, Regular expression to parse data

Tags: php, regex

I have data in the format:

Football - 101 Carolina Panthers +15 -110 for Game

Football - 101 Carolina Panthers/Pittsburgh Steelers under 36½ -110 for Game

Football - 102 Pittsburgh Steelers -9 -120 for 1st Half

---

How to transform this into a PHP array:

```
$game_data[] = array( 'sport_type'  => 'Football',
                      'game_number' => 101,
                      'game_name'   => 'Carolina Panthers',
                      'runline_odd' => '+15 -110',
                      'total_odd'   => '',
                      'odd_type'    => 'runline',
                      'period'      => 'Game' );

$game_data[] = array( 'sport_type'  => 'Football',
                      'game_number' => 101,
                      'game_name'   => 'Carolina Panthers/Pittsburgh Steelers',
                      'runline_odd' => '',
                      'total_odd'   => 'under 36&#189; -110',
                      'odd_type'    => 'total_odd',
                      'period'      => 'Game' );

$game_data[] = array( 'sport_type'  => 'Football',
                      'game_number' => 102,
                      'game_name'   => 'Pittsburgh Steelers',
                      'runline_odd' => '-9 -120',
                      'total_odd'   => '',
                      'odd_type'    => 'runline',
                      'period'      => '1st Half' );
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Your question reads as if you're asking for a ready solution, but have zero intention to learn and/or understand regular expressions.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  In the future, if you want to display large chunks of code, you can prepend each line with four spaces, as I reformatted your question to do.

Comment: @Antal S-Z: Thank You :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't solve the whole problem for someone, but the `½` character made it interesting enough. Now, I'm not a super expert on regexes so this might not be the most optimized or elegant solution, but it seems to get the job done. At least with the provided sample input.

EDIT: Oops. Didn't catch that `under` was actually part of the `runline_odd` data. So this does actually not currently get the job done. I'll be back.

EDIT2: Revised the regex slightly and it now correctly matches between `runline_odd` and `runline_total`.

```
<?php
$input = array(
'Football - 101 Carolina Panthers +15 -110 for Game',
'Football - 101 Carolina Panthers/Pittsburgh Steelers under 36½ -110 for Game',
'Football - 102 Pittsburgh Steelers -9 -120 for 1st Half'
);

$regex = '^(?<sport_type>[[:alpha:]]*) - '.
         '(?<game_number>[0-9]*) '.
         '('.
            '(?<game_nameb>[[:alpha:]\/ ]*?) '.
            '(?<runline_total>(under ([0-9\x{00BD}]+){1}) ((-|\+)?([-+0-9\x{00BD}]+){1})) for '.
         '|'.
            '(?<game_namea>[[:alpha:]\/ ]*) '.
            '(?<runline_odd>((-|\+)?([0-9\x{00BD}]+){1}) ((-|\+)?([-+0-9\x{00BD}]+){1})) for '.
         ')'.
         '(?<period>.*)$';


$game_data = array();

foreach ($input as $in) {
    $matches = false;
    $cnt = preg_match('/' . $regex . '/ui', $in, $matches);

    if ($cnt && is_array($matches) && count($matches)) {
        if (empty($matches['game_nameb'])) {
            $game_name = $matches['game_namea'];
            $runline_odd = $matches['runline_odd'];
            $total_odd = '';
        } else {
            $game_name = $matches['game_nameb'];
            $runline_odd = '';
            $total_odd = $matches['runline_total'];
        }


        $result = array(
            'sport_type' => $matches['sport_type'],
            'game_number' => $matches['game_number'],
            'game_name' => $game_name,
            'runline_odd' => $runline_odd,
            'total_odd' => $total_odd,
            'period' => $matches['period']
        );

        array_push($game_data, $result);
    }
}

var_dump($game_data);
```

This produces the following:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/php preg-match.php 
array(3) {
[0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["sport_type"]=>
    string(8) "Football"
    ["game_number"]=>
    string(3) "101"
    ["game_name"]=>
    string(17) "Carolina Panthers"
    ["runline_odd"]=>
    string(8) "+15 -110"
    ["total_odd"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["period"]=>
    string(4) "Game"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["sport_type"]=>
    string(8) "Football"
    ["game_number"]=>
    string(3) "101"
    ["game_name"]=>
    string(37) "Carolina Panthers/Pittsburgh Steelers"
    ["runline_odd"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["total_odd"]=>
    string(15) "under 36½ -110"
    ["period"]=>
    string(4) "Game"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["sport_type"]=>
    string(8) "Football"
    ["game_number"]=>
    string(3) "102"
    ["game_name"]=>
    string(19) "Pittsburgh Steelers"
    ["runline_odd"]=>
    string(7) "-9 -120"
    ["total_odd"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["period"]=>
    string(8) "1st Half"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sarah: I was aware of that. Took me a while to modify the regex, but now it's working.

Comment: It's not matching the 2nd string :) which results in array with 2 elements.

Comment: @Sarah: As you can see from my provided sample output, it should indeed work fine, so I suspect the problem lies elsewhere. Can you check: a) Which PHP version are you running it on? b) Which encoding is the data in? -- I'd say it's likely to be an encoding problem. The `preg_match` with the `u` flag expects unicode input. Perhaps you need to `utf8_encode` your input.

Comment: @Sarah: brilliant, glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

Following works except the case where there is an under after gmae name:

```
/([^-]+)\s*-\s*(\d+)\s*([^\d+-]+)\s*((?:under\s*)?[\d\s+-]+)\s*for\s*(.+)/
```

Explanation:

```
([^-]+): Match anything other than -, which is separating gmae name from other details.
\s*-\s*: - surrounded with spaces
(\d+)  : Game number
([^\d+-]+): Anything other than +, -, a digit. Matches gmae name.
((?:under\s*)?[\d\s+-]+): runline odd or total odd.
```

PS:

1. Take care of the cases where there is 'under'. The regex above is dumping it with game_name.
2. Take care of unicode chars.

Comment: You can image the user has more then 3 line of inputs and it's not going to work every time...

Comment: @danip, true, and i don't even know football to know all possible cases. But based on the three lines (apart from the under case which i mentioned) i do see a pattern: `(string) - (number) (string) (number) for (string)`.